# I Can't Execute Function in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I faced of a weird problem. I never saw before. In the code, asynctask executed, and in doInBackground I call one function but function doesn't execute. What is the problem ? I don't get any error message, just function doesn't executed and `item_details` return null.

Note: In the asynctask, `int x` value is not null.

Here is the asynctask

```
public class GetItemDetailAS extends AsyncTask<String,String[],String[]>{
        String ParamID;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ItemActivity.this);

        public GetItemDetailAS(String ParamID){
            this.ParamID=ParamID;
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
         }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            int x = Integer.valueOf(ParamID);
            GetItemDetail(x);   

            return item_details;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String[] item_details){
             _title.setText(item_details[5]);
             _sellerName.setText(item_details[1]);
             _location.setText(item_details[6]);
             _price.setText(item_details[3]);
             _desc.setText(item_details[4]);

             if(item_details[7].toString().length()<20){
                    _picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.desire_z);
                }
                else{
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(item_details[7], Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
                    _picture.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                }
             dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Here is the function

```
private String[] GetItemDetail(int paramID){
        PropertyInfo id = new PropertyInfo();
        id.name= "itemid";
        id.setValue(paramID);
        id.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "GetItem");
        request.addProperty(id);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut=request;
        envelope.dotNet = true;     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://service.melihmucuk.com/ShopArWS.asmx");
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/GetItem", envelope);  
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){    
               Object property = response.getProperty(i);
               if(property instanceof SoapObject){
                   SoapObject item = (SoapObject) property;
                   String seller_id = String.valueOf(item.getProperty("seller_id").toString());
                   String seller_name = item.getProperty("seller_name").toString();
                   String item_id = String.valueOf(item.getProperty("item_id").toString());
                   String price = item.getProperty("price").toString() + " TL";
                   String desc = item.getProperty("desc").toString();
                   String title = item.getProperty("title").toString();
                   String location = item.getProperty("location").toString();
                   String picture = item.getProperty("picture").toString();
                        item_details[0] = seller_id;
                        item_details[1] = seller_name;
                        item_details[2] = item_id;
                        item_details[3] = price;
                        item_details[4] = desc;
                        item_details[5] = title;
                        item_details[6] = location;
                        item_details[7] = picture;
               }
            }
        }
             catch (Exception e) {          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return item_details; 
    }
```

onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);

        _title =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
        _sellerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sellerNameTxt);
        _location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LocationNameTxt);
        _price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PriceNameTxt);
        _desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descNameText);
        _picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BuyButton);

        veriler = getIntent().getExtras();       
        item_id=veriler.getString("item_id");
        item_details = new String[8];

        new GetItemDetailAS(item_id).execute();

        bundle = new Bundle();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialogConfirm = new Dialog(context);
                dialogConfirm.setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
                dialogConfirm.setTitle("Shopping Cart");
                dialogConfirm.setCancelable(false);

                dTitle = (TextView) dialogConfirm.findViewById(R.id.cartItemTitle);
                dPrice = (TextView) dialogConfirm.findViewById(R.id.cartItemPrice);
                dTitle.setText(item_details[5].toString()+":");
                dPrice.setText(item_details[3]);

                Button completeButton = (Button) dialogConfirm.findViewById(R.id.cartCompleteButton);
                Button cancelButton = (Button) dialogConfirm.findViewById(R.id.cartCompleteCancel);

                completeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // complete

                        dialogConfirm.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // cancel
                        dialogConfirm.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialogConfirm.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `item_details` get initialized somewhere? Maybe you just get a NPE when trying to fill it with data and you dont' see the output of `e.printStackTrace();`. Replace it with a real Log output. also replace

```
GetItemDetail(x);   
return item_details;
```

with

```
return GetItemDetail(x);
```

Comment: item_details initialized in onCreate, I used many times this structure and I didn't see anything like this. I tried `return GetItemDetail(x);` and didn't change anything.

Comment: Add Log statements and step trough the code in debug mode so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First think I can see is that your function private String[] GetItemDetail(int paramID) returning value, but you are not assigning it to nay variable: GetItemDetail(x)

Try with:

> ```
> @Override
>          protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
>              int x = Integer.valueOf(ParamID);
>              return GetItemDetail(x);   
>          }
> ```

instead of

> ```
> @Override
>         protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
>             int x = Integer.valueOf(ParamID);
>             GetItemDetail(x);   
>             return item_details;
>         }
> ```

I do not see the your whole class, so I can't see how you are introduce item_details in your GetItemDetail function?

Comment: Can you check what is returned from function GetItemDetail()(debug it)?
So we can separate problems. If this function returns correct value, problem is in passing values to onPostExecute. If function returns wrong value, we can hunt problem there.

Comment: Hey, you misunderstood. `GetItemDetail()` didn't execute. This is the problem. So item_details returned null.

Comment: OK.Sry. It is not executed at all, or it do not return expected result (it returns null)?

Comment: Yes, function didn't execute, therefore item_details returned null.

Comment: Whow! Interesting! It is not possible to have function in code flow and has it not called.

Please, do not get me wrong, but are you 100% sure that your code flow do not enter getItemDetail()? 
If you place breakpoint inside it (first line), it will not be called? 

This is wird problem, so I would like you to triple check flow.

If you are sure, than I can only sugest you to reset your complete environment, and to clean your project.